# Background image doesn't appear on a specific page

Tags: css, layout, html, stylesheet

On this site: http://walkman.pk/aserdus2/tagok.php
I have two background-images on the left and right side, which doesn't appear, and I can't figure it out why ?
Every other page of the website works fine. It seems that some `<div>` elements are not closed properly. When I watch it with chrome inspector, I see that the `content` div is very thin, but I don't understand the reason of this.
What should I do to show up the images?

Comment: make sure you have a width/height on the divs.  Can you post a screenshot of what it should look like and some html/css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only floating elements inside `#content`, so its height is zero. You can fix this by setting `overflow` to something other than `visible`:

```css
#content {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Voilà:

[image: With floats fixed]

Answer (score 1):

That's because both elements with class `block` are floating and therefore the element with id `content` has no height (which has the background images). So you need to give height to the `content` element (`height: 250px`) should solve the problem.

Comment: this messes up the other pages and the footer will be inside of the text !

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `#content {}`:

`height: 600px;` (or however high the images are)

I tried it with Inspect Element and the pictures appeared.

Good luck!

Comment: same problem; at long pages, the footer will be inside of text

Comment: When I look at the page you provided, it now works. I see that `overflow: hidden` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<div id="content">

...

<div style="clear:both"></div>
<!-- CONTENT END -->
</div>
```

OR 
http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html

```
<div id="content" class="clearfix">

...  

<!-- CONTENT END -->
</div>
```

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```